# Backbone.js: two collections, same models, listening for events.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two collections that contain the same models. If one collection makes a change to a model listeners on the other collection do not get triggered? Any known reason why this would happen?

Comment: @Esailija so it should be throwing change events on the other collection, correct?

Comment: Yes it should, the events fire in the model, they can have listeners anywhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks, there must be another issue at hand here.

Comment: are you instantiating two different models by accident?

Answer (score 2):

You could see if the events are triggered by making this hook:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger = function(){
    var old = Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger;

    return function(e){
        console.log( "model event triggered: "+e );
        return old.apply( this, arguments );
    };

}();
```

It should log whenever a backbone model internally triggers an event